# Javascript assigning global variables to themself

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain this (code in global scope)

```
var a = a || 4 // a exists & is 4
window.a = window.a || 4 // a exists & is 4
window.a = a || 4 // a is undefined error
a = a || 4 // a is undefined error
```

An explanation of what the difference is between these 4 assignments and why some handle it properly but others don't.

[Edit] this particular example was tested on the V8 Chrome console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var a = a || 4 // var a is evaluated at compile time, so a is undefined here
window.a = window.a || 4 // window.a is simply undefined
window.a = a || 4 // no var a, therefore the variable doesn't exist, = reference error
a = a || 4 // again, no var, reference error
```

The `var` statement declares the variable/function in the closest encapsulating scope and sets it to `undefined`. When there's not `var`, there's no variable/function declared at all. Therefore the reference error.

Some examples.

`function` statement:

```
foo(); // works
function foo() {}

bar(); // TypeError: undefined is not a function
var bar = function(){};
```

`var` statement:

```
function test(foo) {        
    if (foo) {
        var bar = 0; // defined at compile time in the scope of function test
    } else {
        bar = 4; // sets the bar above, not the global bar
    }
    return bar;
}

console.log(test(false)); // 4
console.log(bar); // ReferenceError
```

Comment: Of course the difference here is an undefined property on an object and an undeclared object. Why is a undefined at compile time but undeclared at run time?

Comment: The `var` statment declares the variable in the closest encapsulating scope and sets it to `undefined`. When there's not `var`, there's no variable declared at all. Therefore the reference error.

Comment: Nice one I didnt know a `var bar = 0` was defined at compile time in the function scope. Thats why I only need one `var` statement instead of two